# How can I mount easyrtc on webserver?

Tags: node.js, webserver, webrtc, easyrtc

I'm trying to develop a video chat web-application with webrtc using easyrtc. I have developed it on my local machine. It runs well with node.js server on my localhost. But how can I mount it on my web-server? That means, when a user visit my website, he will able to video chat by this.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple..put your project on sever, open firewall that allows connection throws in and out. Then integrate with your authentication system..
Done

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed the application on node.js, you only have to follow the deploying procedure for an node.js app. In case that you have an app (php, ruby, python or others) that uses easyrtc as an signaling server, you can deploy your easyrtc and app to the same server or separately.

On the secon case you should use `easyrtc.setSocketUrl("//mydomain.com:8080");` to avoid connection issues related to socket.io. For more info on this see:

https://easyrtc.com/docs/easyrtc_with_other_servers.php

Also remember that you application needs to work with `https` to work correctly in Chrome. See this:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc